# Looping through dataframes in R

Tags: r, loops, csv, if-statement, data.table

I am trying to loop through all the rows of a column in a `DataFrame`. I read in the csv using `data.table`. I am new to R and was wondering what way I would go about doing something like this:

```
for i in row_2_of_dataframe: 
 if i == 0: 
  #Do something to that value
 else: 
  #Leave it the way it is
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: When using R, we rarely explicitly loop through data.frames. It would be better if you provided some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data input and the desired output for that input.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the ifelse() function. For example;

```
mydf$column_name <- ifelse(mydf$column_name == 0, "do something",mydf$column_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
frame <- data.frame(x = as.character(rep("bye", 11)), 
                    y = as.character(0:10),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(frame[, 2])) {
  if (frame[, 2][i] == 0) {
    frame[, 2][i] <- "hi"
  }
}
```

You don't even really need an else statement.

Furthermore,

```
frame[, 2]
```

selects the second column and turns it into a vector.

```
frame[, 1]
```

would select the first column.

```
frame[1, ]
```

would select the first *row*.

And so on.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for